# Solidity contract - Best way to airdrop a single time a user

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, transfer, airdrop

I've got this very simple Airdrop contract below:

```
contract ERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)public returns(bool);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner)public view returns(uint balance);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens)public returns(bool success);
}

contract SimpleAirdrop {

    ERC20 public token;
    uint256 amount = 1000 * 10**18 //18 decimals token

    function SimpleAirdrop(address _tokenAddr) public {
        token = ERC20(_tokenAddr);
    }

    function getAirdrop() public {
        token.transfer(msg.sender, amount); 
    }
}
```

I can deploy the contract with a given ERC20 address so I should be able to send token to this contract and users can call the getAirdrop() method and receive 1000 tokens

**How can I prevent a user from being airdrop more than 1 time ?**
I could check the user balance but that doesn't proove he didn't received the airdrop already. Can I store a list of address that called the airdrop method ? What would be the gaz impact ?

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is create a mapping between the getAirdrop function and the user's address.

Then add a method into the getAirdrop fuction that if the airdrop is successful, the Boolean goes to true.

1. Check if the address have done it before

//has the user gotten airdrop before?

```
mapping(address => bool) public hasClaimed;
```

2. Incorporate the logic into the airdrop function

Then into the getAirdrop function, add

```
 function getAirdrop() public {
 require(hasClaimed[msg.sender] == false) ;
 token.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
 hasClaimed[msg.sender] == true;
}
```

Unfortunately a user can just create another address and claim more, but this is something you cannot stop solely with the Smart Contract.